# Adding link to slides

Tags: carousel

I used this carousel from Codepen.

> https://codepen.io/dangvanthanh/pen/AgHnB

I added links to each slide, but when I did, all the slides link to the link of the last slide. I even tried adding an onlick event onclick="window.location='https://codepen.io'" but without success.. Please help.

Fyi, Im a designer, not a front end developer, and Im just trying to put together a carousel for a website..

```css
/**
 * Carousel.sass
 * @author: Dang Van Thanh
 * @github: https://github.com/dangvanthanh/carousel.sass
 * @description: A Simple Carousel Pure CSS Using Sass
 * @version: 1.0.0
 */
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(5), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(2), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(1), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(3), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(2), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(4), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(3), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(5), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(4), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  z-index: 3;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item,
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__prev > label,
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__next > label {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(4) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel__items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
}
.carousel__item img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.carousel__prev > label, .carousel__next > label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.carousel__prev > label:hover, .carousel__prev > label:focus, .carousel__next > label:hover, .carousel__next > label:focus {
  opacity: .5 !important;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before, .carousel__prev > label:after, .carousel__next > label:before, .carousel__next > label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before, .carousel__next > label:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 0%, #fff 10%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 10%), linear-gradient(to left, #fff 0%, #fff 10%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 10%);
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
}
.carousel__prev > label {
  left: 2%;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before {
  left: 35%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.carousel__next > label {
  right: 2%;
}
.carousel__next > label:before {
  left: 10%;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__nav > label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 .125%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel">
    <input type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel[]" checked   onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com'">
    <input type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel[]">
 <input type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel[]">
    <input type="radio" id="carousel-4" name="carousel[]">
    <input type="radio" id="carousel-5" name="carousel[]">
    <ul class="carousel__items">
    
     <li class="carousel__item" onclick="window.location='http://google.com'"> 
        <a href"http://google.com">
    <img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cTEgPOnd3l8/U8-EmaZ4KNI/AAAAAAAABc8/6eacbALkQ6A/w1358-h905-no/carousel-1.JPG" alt="" style="border: 3px solid red">
   </a>  
  </li>
  
        <li class="carousel__item">
    <a href"http://instagram.com">
    <img src="//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ntVHbbWX5eo/U8-EmV8P4cI/AAAAAAAABc4/ICYBGkcztTc/w1358-h905-no/carousel-2.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    </li>
        <li class="carousel__item">
    <a href"http://facebook.com">
    <img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-batEXUZE_e4/U8-EmLF9-hI/AAAAAAAABc0/J3tJVUa6Buk/w1358-h905-no/carousel-3.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    </li>
        <li class="carousel__item">
    <a href"http://tiktok.com">
    <img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gywqIeMvel0/U8-EolKdtkI/AAAAAAAABdM/G0-NHuvvJUU/w1358-h905-no/carousel-4.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    </li>
        <li class="carousel__item">
    <a href"http://pinterest.com">
    <img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/--2iANjL3ikc/U8-EoGJ18mI/AAAAAAAABdI/fBe-q3Gos6Y/w1358-h905-no/carousel-5.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 <div class="carousel__prev">
    <label for="carousel-1"></label>
    <label for="carousel-2"></label>
    <label for="carousel-3"></label>
    <label for="carousel-4"></label>
    <label for="carousel-5"></label>
 </div>
 <div class="carousel__next">
   <label for="carousel-1"></label>
   <label for="carousel-2"></label>
   <label for="carousel-3"></label>
   <label for="carousel-4"></label>
   <label for="carousel-5"></label>
 </div>
 <div class="carousel__nav">
   <label for="carousel-1"></label>
   <label for="carousel-2"></label>
   <label for="carousel-3"></label>
   <label for="carousel-4"></label>
   <label for="carousel-5"></label>
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hmz777/pen/wvGmKgP)

You were seeing this behaviour bacause the transition was using the slide opacity so the last link will always be in the front.

```css
/**
 * Carousel.sass
 * @author: Dang Van Thanh
 * @github: https://github.com/dangvanthanh/carousel.sass
 * @description: A Simple Carousel Pure CSS Using Sass
 * @version: 1.0.0
 */
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(5), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(2), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(1), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(3), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(2), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(4), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(3), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(5), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__prev > label:nth-child(4), .carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__next > label:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  z-index: 3;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item,
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__prev > label,
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .carousel__next > label {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(3):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(4):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(4) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__items .carousel__item:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(5):checked ~ .carousel__nav > label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel__items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
}
.carousel__item img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.carousel__prev > label, .carousel__next > label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.carousel__prev > label:hover, .carousel__prev > label:focus, .carousel__next > label:hover, .carousel__next > label:focus {
  opacity: .5 !important;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before, .carousel__prev > label:after, .carousel__next > label:before, .carousel__next > label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before, .carousel__next > label:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 0%, #fff 10%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 10%), linear-gradient(to left, #fff 0%, #fff 10%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 10%);
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
}
.carousel__prev > label {
  left: 2%;
}
.carousel__prev > label:before {
  left: 35%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.carousel__next > label {
  right: 2%;
}
.carousel__next > label:before {
  left: 10%;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.carousel__nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__nav > label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 .125%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <input type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel[]" checked>
        <input type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel[]">
     <input type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel[]">
        <input type="radio" id="carousel-4" name="carousel[]">
        <input type="radio" id="carousel-5" name="carousel[]">
        <ul class="carousel__items">
      <li class="carousel__item"><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cTEgPOnd3l8/U8-EmaZ4KNI/AAAAAAAABc8/6eacbALkQ6A/w1358-h905-no/carousel-1.JPG" alt=""></a></li>
      <li class="carousel__item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ntVHbbWX5eo/U8-EmV8P4cI/AAAAAAAABc4/ICYBGkcztTc/w1358-h905-no/carousel-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li class="carousel__item"><a href="https://www.yahoo.com">
        <img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-batEXUZE_e4/U8-EmLF9-hI/AAAAAAAABc0/J3tJVUa6Buk/w1358-h905-no/carousel-3.jpg" alt="">
      </a></li>
      <li class="carousel__item"><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gywqIeMvel0/U8-EolKdtkI/AAAAAAAABdM/G0-NHuvvJUU/w1358-h905-no/carousel-4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li class="carousel__item"><a href="https://www.github.com"><img src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/--2iANjL3ikc/U8-EoGJ18mI/AAAAAAAABdI/fBe-q3Gos6Y/w1358-h905-no/carousel-5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
     <div class="carousel__prev">
        <label for="carousel-1"></label>
        <label for="carousel-2"></label>
        <label for="carousel-3"></label>
        <label for="carousel-4"></label>
        <label for="carousel-5"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel__next">
       <label for="carousel-1"></label>
       <label for="carousel-2"></label>
       <label for="carousel-3"></label>
       <label for="carousel-4"></label>
       <label for="carousel-5"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel__nav">
       <label for="carousel-1"></label>
       <label for="carousel-2"></label>
       <label for="carousel-3"></label>
       <label for="carousel-4"></label>
       <label for="carousel-5"></label>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```